# Groupby multiple keys with lodash or plain js

Tags: javascript, lodash

I've been trying to group by multiple keys with lodash but it's not returning the correct results. **The aim is to group by `state` and `details`** but in this case it's joining/grouping docIds `333333` and `444444` which although have equal `state` (rejected), don't have the same `id`'s in `details` (=> different people) so they don't share both conditions: `state` and `id`'s in `details`.

It seems my current code does work with multiple criteria but once only one of the conditions exists it still performs the grouping, while I wanted to only group if both criteria were satisfied.

As for lodash approach It should show:

```
[
  {
    "docId": "222222,1111111",
    "details": [
      {
        "id": 20656,
        "type": "Claimant",
        "name": "First Name Last Name"
      },
      {
        "id": 10000,
        "type": "Fellow",
        "name": "Fellow First Name Fellow Last Name"
      }
    ],
    "state": "accepted",
  },
  {
    "docId": "333333",
    "details": [
      {
        "id": 10000,
        "type": "Fellow",
        "name": "Fellow First Name Fellow Last Name"
      }
    ],
    "state": "rejected",
  },
  {
    "docId": "444444",
    "details": [
      {
        "id": 20656,
        "type": "Claimant",
        "name": "First Name Last Name"
      },
    ],
    "state": "rejected",
  }
]
```

I'm open to use plain js and have no problem in getting for example `"docId": [{"333333"},{"444444"}]` instead of comma separated values , or slightly different final result as long as the grouping in the end obeys to the same rules but I wasn't able to achieve the intended result either with plain js so I moved to lodash which seemed simpler.

In the end I will be needing some sorting to prioritize `state`, then groups with only one person in details and when one person, prioritize the ones with `claimant` but that's something that should be done afterwards, right?

Help would be much appreciated.

```js
const data = [
    {
      docId: 222222,
      state: "accepted",
      details: [
        {
          id: 20656,
          type: "Claimant",
          name: "First Name Last Name",
        },
        {
          id: 10000,
          type: "Fellow",
          name: "Fellow First Name Fellow Last Name",
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      docId: 1111111,
      state: "accepted",
      details: [
              {
          id: 10000,
          type: "Fellow",
          name: "Fellow First Name Fellow Last Name",
        },
        {
          id: 20656,
          type: "Claimant",
          name: "First Name Last Name",
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      docId: 333333,
      state: "rejected",
      details: [
        {
          id: 10000,
          type: "Fellow",
          name: "Fellow First Name Last Name",
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      docId: 444444,
      state: "rejected",
      details: [
        {
          id: 20656,
          type: "Claimant",
          name: "First Name Last Name",
        }
      ]
    }
  ];


const grouped = _(data)
  .groupBy(({details,state}) => `${details},${state}`)
  .map((value, key) => ({
    docId: _.map(value, 'docId').join(','),
    details: value[0].details,
    state: value[0].state,
    document_file_name: value[0].document_file_name,
  }))
  .value()

console.log(grouped)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.21/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: can you add the result as well?

Comment: @NinaScholz added expected result

Comment: are details with same `id` equal? what should happen if there anot the same amount of same state details?

Comment: @NinaScholz each `id` inside `details` corresponds to a person. If a `docId` has only in `details`  for example `id: 10000`, the docId's that have **only** that same `id` in `details` should be grouped together. If a `docId` has in `details` `id: 10000` and `id: 20656`, the docId's that **only** have both those id's in `details` should be grouped. Baring in mind that they should only be grouped if they have the same `state`

Comment: @NinaScholz summing up: in `docId` after grouping it should show all `docIds` that match both criteria: `state` and full `id`'s inside `details`. Is it clearer now? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First collect `id` by `state` and `docId`.
Second group collected data by `state` and sorted `id` and build new objects.

```js
const
    data = [{ docId: 222222, document_file_name: "4020653_FileName.pdf", document_updated_at: "2020-07-08T19:41:28.385Z", state: "accepted", details: [{ id: 20656, type: "Claimant", name: "First Name Last Name" }, { id: 10000, type: "Fellow", name: "Fellow First Name Fellow Last Name" }] }, { docId: 1111111, document_file_name: "4020600_FileName.pdf", document_updated_at: "2020-07-08T19:41:28.385Z", state: "accepted", details: [{ id: 10000, type: "Fellow", name: "Fellow First Name Fellow Last Name" }, { id: 20656, type: "Claimant", name: "First Name Last Name" }] }, { docId: 333333, document_file_name: "4020890_FileName.pdf", document_updated_at: "2020-07-08T19:41:28.385Z", state: "rejected", details: [{ id: 10000, type: "Fellow", name: "Fellow First Name Last Name" }] }, { docId: 444444, document_file_name: "4020672_FileName.pdf", document_updated_at: "2020-07-08T19:41:28.385Z", state: "rejected", details: [{ id: 20656, type: "Claimant", name: "First Name Last Name" }] }],
    ids = {},
    temp = data.reduce((r, { docId, state, details }) => {
        const key = [state, docId].join('|');
        details.forEach(o => {
            ids[o.id] = o;
            (r[key] ??= []).push(o.id);
        });
        return r;
    }, {}),
    grouped = Object.values(Object
        .entries(temp)
        .reduce((r, [k, v]) => {
            const
                [state, docId] = k.split('|'),
                key = [state, v.sort().join('|')].join('#');
            r[key] ??= { docId: '' , details: v.map(id => ids[id]), state };
            r[key].docId += (r[key].docId && ', ') + docId;
            return r;
        }, {}));

console.log(grouped);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```